# Redirecting to another page if accessed through mobiles

Tags: javascript, dom, mobile

I'm looking for a script to redirect to another page if it is loaded on a mobile device ( to be exact, devices that operate with touch screens instead of a mouse).

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks Again!

Answer (score -1):

```
fucntion redirectIfTouchDevice(url){
    if(('ontouchstart' in window)|| (navigator.MaxTouchPoints > 0)|| (navigator.msMaxTouchPoints > 0)){
        window.location = url;
    }
}
```

Call At document load `redirectIfTouchDevice('http://you/url');`

Comment: Updated Fix, one typo was there

Comment: Thanks for your reply, so to confirm if the main site is www.example.com & the redirect page is www.examplemobile.com; the code would read; function redirectIfTouchDevice(‘http://example.com){
    if(('ontouchstart' in window)|| (navigator.MaxTouchPoints > 0)|| (navigator.msMaxTouchPoints > 0)){
        window.location = (‘http://examplemobile.com);
    }
}

Comment: In example.com you will add this script so, when an user loads example.com in an touch screen device the user will be redirected to examplemobile.com